# Oracle WSM local optimization disabled by any policy

Tags: oracle, weblogic, soa, policies

I have a lot of composites on my Oracle SOA Suite 11g server.
They are succesfully invoking each other using Local Invocation / Optimization.
But since I am trying to attach any policy, local optimization disappear.
I have checked in Oracle EM - local optimization is enabled for this policies.
I have tried to force local optimization explicitly in composites - no result.